# Unable to access a Mac self hosted WCF service from Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, soap, xamarin

I'll state immediately that I'm very new to Xamarin development. That said, here is the background:

We have a Silverlight application which is able to connect successfully to a self-hosted WCF service when it is hosted in Windows. Since we need this service to be successfully hosted on a Mac as well, we ported it over to Xamarin, and could connect to the self-hosted service using a simple non-Silverlight console app (i.e. manually setting up endpoints and channel).

When attempting to connect via Silverlight, I'm getting the following exception:

> An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI '...'. This
>   could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way
>   without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is
>   unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the
>   service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows
>   SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by
>   using internal types in the web service proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception
>   for more details.

Is it possible in Xamarin to serve up the access and cross domain policies via a stream (as in [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/03/07/enabling-cross-domain-calls-for-silverlight-apps-on-self-hosted-web-services.aspx))? I'm also wondering what, if any, other changes would need to occur in the client's ServiceReferences.ClientConfig.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by setting up a service host and a separate web service host for serving the access policy. I still leveraged the code from the example referenced in the original post, but just separated the serving of the access policy into its own web service host instead of being an additional endpoint on the main service host.

```
    Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://192.168.2.230:8090/MyService");
    Uri webHttpUrl = new Uri("http://192.168.2.230:8090/");
    //Create ServiceHost
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), httpUrl);
    WebServiceHost webHost = new WebServiceHost (typeof(AccessPolicyService), webHttpUrl);
```